# NodeJS API Mongodb Not Saving Data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

recently I start a create a nodejs and mongo API ,  try to save the data but, can't save any info. the only info can get is the ID generated when make a POST request. I use POSTMANT to test de API but not success to save data. the only info can get is just the ID here's my code.

this is the API Routes and Model are in the same file[api objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmKeL.png).
api.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

// MongoDb URL 

const dbHost = 'mongodb://localhost/motiva';

//conectamos la BD

mongoose.connect(dbHost, function(err) {
    if(err){
    console.log('No nos podemos conectar a la BD')
   }else {
    console.log('Conexion Exitosa')
  }
});

// Creamos el Schema  de la BD

const applicantSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
workbefore: {type:String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
payrange: String,
desposition: {type:String, enum: ['Costumer Service Representative', 
'Spanish Costumer Service', 'Claims Representative', 'Salex 
Executive', 'Other']},
name: String,
psourname: String,
msourname: String,
dob: Date,
age: Number,
gender: {type:String, enum:['Male', 'Female']},
pofbirth: String,
nationality: String,
city: {type:String, enum: ['Tijuana', 'Tecate', 'Mexicali', 
'Rosarito', 'Ensenada']},
satate: {type:String, enum: ['Baja California', 'Other']},
zipcode: Number,
street: String,
streetNumber: String,
appartNumber: String,
homePhone: Number,
mobileNumber: Number,
secondaryPhone: String,
radio: String,
email: String,
relation: {type: String, enum: ['Single', 'Married', 'Separated', 
'Living Together']},
spouseName: String,
childrens:{ type: String, enum: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 'Other']},
fatherName: String,
motherName: String,
emergencyContact: String,
relationshipContact: String,
relcontactPhone: String,
dependentYou: String,
timeResident: String,
education: String,
school: String,
graduationDate: Date,
degree: String,
englishProficiency: Number,
englishWriteLevel: String,
computerProficiency:{type: String, enum:['Basic', 'Intermediate', 
'Advanced']},
validVisa:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
bodyTattos:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
memberClub: String,
criminalRecord:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
prisionMexico:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
shift:{type: String, enum: ['Morning', 'Afternoon', 'Night']},
callWork:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
nightShift:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
refName: String,
refOccupation: String,
refPhone: String,
refKnow: String,
refEmail: String,
workExperince:{type: String, enum: ['Yes', 'No']},
companyName: String,
companyCountry: String,
companyDate: Date,
leaveJob: String,
jobTitle: String,
supervisorName: String,

});

// Creamos el Modelo 

const Applicant = mongoose.model('Applicant', applicantSchema);

// Obtenemos todos los Aplicantes GET ALL
router.get('/applicants', (req, res) => {
Applicant.find({}, (err, applicants) => {
    if (err) res.status(500).send(error)
    res.status(200).json(applicants);
  });
});

// Obetenmos los Aplicantes de Manera Indivudual

router.get('/applicants/:id', (req, res) => {
    Applicant.findById.apply(req.param.id, (err, applicants) => {
    if(err) res.status(500).send(error)
    res.status(200).json(applicants);
   });
});

//Creamos el Applicante en la Base de Datos
router.post('/applicants', (req, res) => {
var applicants = new Applicant();
applicants.workbefore = req.body.workbefore;
    applicants.payrange = req.body.payrange;
    applicants.desposition = req.body.desposition;
    applicants.name = req.body.name;
    applicants.psourname = req.body.psourname;
    applicants.msourname = req.body.msourname;
    applicants.dob = req.body.dob;
    applicants.age = req.body.age;
    applicants.gender = req.body.gender;
    applicants.pofbirth = req.body.pofbirth;
    applicants.nationality = req.body.nationality;
    applicants.city = req.body.city ;
    applicants.satate = req.body.satate;
    applicants.zipcode = req.body.zipcode;
    applicants.street = req.body.street;
    applicants.streetNumber = req.body.streetNumber;
    applicants.appartNumber = req.body.appartNumber;
    applicants.homePhone = req.body.homePhone;
    applicants.mobileNumber = req.body.mobileNumber;
    applicants.secondaryPhone = req.body.secondaryPhone;
    applicants.radio = req.body.radio;
    applicants.email = req.body.email;
    applicants.relation = req.body.relation;
    applicants.spouseName = req.body.spouseName;
    applicants.childrens = req.body.childrens;
    applicantsfatherName = req.body.fatherName;
    applicants.motherName = req.body.motherName;
    applicants.emergencyContact = req.body.emergencyContact;
    applicants.relationshipContact = req.body.relationshipContact;
    applicants.relcontactPhone = req.body.relcontactPhone;
    applicants.dependentYou = req.body.dependentYou;
    applicants.timeResident = req.body.timeResident;
    applicants.education = req.body.education;
    applicants.school = req.body.school;
    applicants.graduationDate = req.body.graduationDate;
    applicants.degree = req.body.degree;
    applicants.englishProficiency = req.body.englishProficiency;
    applicants.englishWriteLevel = req.body.englishWriteLevel;
    applicants.computerProficiency = req.body.computerProficiency;
    applicants.validVisa = req.body.validVisa;
    applicants.bodyTattos = req.body.bodyTattos;
    applicants.memberClub = req.body.memberClub;
    applicants.criminalRecord = req.body.criminalRecord;
    applicants.prisionMexico = req.body.prisionMexico;
    applicants.shift = req.body.shift;
    applicants.callWork = req.body.callWork;
    applicants.nightShift = req.body.nightShift;
    applicants.refName = req.body.refName;
    applicants.refOccupation = req.body.refOccupation;
    applicants.refPhone = req.body.refPhone;
    applicants.refKnow = req.body.refKnow;
    applicants.refEmail = req.body.refemail;
    applicants.workExperince = req.body.workExperince;
    applicants.companyName = req.body.companyName;
    applicants.companyCountry = req.body.companyCountry;
    applicants.companyDate = req.body.companyDate;
    applicants.leaveJob = req.body.leaveJob;
    applicants.jobTitle = req.body.jobTitle;
    applicants.supervisorName = req.body.supervisorName;  

    applicants.save(error => {
    if (error) res.status(500).send(error);

    res.status(201).json({
        message: 'Applicant created successfully'
     });
  });

});

// Obtenemos nuestro API List
router.get('/', (req,res) => {
res.send('API Works - API Funcionando');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup the `middleware` to get the data from `req.body`. I don't see any middleware setup in your code.

1) Include the below code to setup the middleware

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = express();
var urlencoded_body_parser = bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(urlencoded_body_parser);
```

2) Add console log on post `/applicants` endpoint

```
console.log(req.body);
```

3) If you get the data on console, the data should get persisted on MongoDB successfully based on the mapping that you have done

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it resolved the problem?